# In tomcat, how to return raw response payload without gzip compression by default After enabling gzip config in server side?

Tags: tomcat, gzip

In tomcat/conf/server.xml, I enabled gzip compression as below.

```
compression="on" compressableMimeType="application/json" compressionMinSize="2048"
```

I'd like to check any solution when client explicitly pass "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" in Request Header, then tomcat retunr response payload with gzip compressed.

Otherwise, When no more key-value in request header, tomcat by default return the payload without gzip compression.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the default behavior of Tomcat. Unless it finds the *Accept-Encoding* header containing the value *gzip*, it will not compress the output.

If you want to implement your own, very specific compression, then you can start with the Tomcat sources `CompressionFilter` and `CompressionServletResponseWrapper`.

Comment: As to the result I tried, when I don't attach any header option for request, it still return the response with "Content-Encoding: gzip". Only when I explicitly attach Header "Accept-Encoding: application/json", then return the response without gzip compression.